# Map array and group by roles in the array object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I have an object array, And in that I have roles as a key, And values init.
Now what I want is I want to group them as per the roles.

This is my data input

```
 {
  users: [
   {
      firstName: 'Will',
      lastName: 'Jacob',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e324187b5fdf167a91dfdbb',
      roles: [ 'ward', 'hospital', 'hr' ],
    },
   {
      firstName: 'Theatre',
      lastName: 'Manager',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e3cf2f0c631a8788be59fc4',
      roles: [ 'ward' ],
    },
   {
      firstName: 'Cinema',
      lastName: 'Manager',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5',
      roles: ['hospital', 'hr' ],
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Cinema2',
      lastName: 'Manager',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5',
      roles: ['ward', 'hr' ],
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Cinema3',
      lastName: 'Manager',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5',
      roles: ['hospital', 'hr' ],
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Cinema4',
      lastName: 'Manager',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5',
      roles: [ 'ward', 'hospital', 'hr' ],
    }
]}
```

AND I want to group it by roles in them and want output something like below

```
{
    ward: [{
      firstName: 'Will',
      lastName: 'Jacob',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e324187b5fdf167a91dfdbb',
      roles: [ 'ward', 'hospital', 'hr' ],
    },
    {   
      firstName: 'Theatre',
      lastName: 'Manager',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e3cf2f0c631a8788be59fc4',
      roles: [ 'ward' ],
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Cinema2',
      lastName: 'Manager',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5',
      roles: ['ward', 'hr' ],
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Cinema3',
      lastName: 'Manager',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5',
      roles: [ 'ward', 'hospital', 'hr' ],
    }],

    hospital: [
    {
      firstName: 'Will',
      lastName: 'Jacob',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e324187b5fdf167a91dfdbb',
      roles: [ 'ward', 'hospital', 'hr' ],
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Cinema',
      lastName: 'Manager',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5',
      roles: ['hospital', 'hr' ],
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Cinema3',
      lastName: 'Manager',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5',
      roles: ['hospital', 'hr' ],
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Cinema4',
      lastName: 'Manager',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5',
      roles: [ 'ward', 'hospital', 'hr' ],
    }],

    hr: [{
      firstName: 'Will',
      lastName: 'Jacob',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e324187b5fdf167a91dfdbb',
      roles: [ 'ward', 'hospital', 'hr' ],
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Cinema',
      lastName: 'Manager',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5',
      roles: ['hospital', 'hr' ],
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Cinema2',
      lastName: 'Manager',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5',
      roles: ['ward', 'hr' ],
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Cinema3',
      lastName: 'Manager',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5',
      roles: ['hospital', 'hr' ],
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Cinema4',
      lastName: 'Manager',
      email: 'sample@sample.com',
      _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5',
      roles: [ 'ward', 'hospital', 'hr' ],
    }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve this? I am looking for a function to process this and return the output as requried.

Comment: Your input is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @Nitheesh yeah man  that's the issue and challenge I am facing.

Comment: This can be fixed from the script or function which generated this, this will not be treated as a valid javascript object

Comment: @Nitheesh anyway I till takecare of that, I have upadated question can you help grouping them?

Comment: There is no `DepartmentUser` anywhere in your code - can you elaborate what the issue is please?

Comment: @TechNerd can you please check the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the `Array.reduce` implementation.

**Logic**

- Loop through each object in array
- Loop through the `roles` array in each object.
- Check if the accumulator have a node with that role, if yes push to that node in accumulator, or else create a node with that name and current object as an element of that node

**Working Example**

```js
const data = {"users":[{"firstName":"Will","lastName":"Jacob","email":"sample@sample.com","_id":"5e324187b5fdf167a91dfdbb","roles":["ward","hospital","hr"]},{"firstName":"Theatre","lastName":"Manager","email":"sample@sample.com","_id":"5e3cf2f0c631a8788be59fc4","roles":["ward"]},{"firstName":"Cinema","lastName":"Manager","email":"sample@sample.com","_id":"5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5","roles":["hospital","hr"]},{"firstName":"Cinema2","lastName":"Manager","email":"sample@sample.com","_id":"5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5","roles":["ward","hr"]},{"firstName":"Cinema3","lastName":"Manager","email":"sample@sample.com","_id":"5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5","roles":["hospital","hr"]},{"firstName":"Cinema4","lastName":"Manager","email":"sample@sample.com","_id":"5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5","roles":["ward","hospital","hr"]}]};

const output = data.users.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  curr.roles.forEach((role) => {
    acc[role] ? acc[role].push(curr) : acc[role] = [curr];
  })
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` to group your data based on roles. You can iterate through each object and create separate array for each role type. This solution only require single traversal of your input array.

```js
const input = { users: [ { firstName: 'Will', lastName: 'Jacob', email: 'sample@sample.com', _id: '5e324187b5fdf167a91dfdbb', roles: [ 'ward', 'hospital', 'hr' ], }, { firstName: 'Theatre', lastName: 'Manager', email: 'sample@sample.com', _id: '5e3cf2f0c631a8788be59fc4', roles: [ 'ward' ], }, { firstName: 'Cinema', lastName: 'Manager', email: 'sample@sample.com', _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5', roles: ['hospital', 'hr' ], }, { firstName: 'Cinema2', lastName: 'Manager', email: 'sample@sample.com', _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5', roles: ['ward', 'hr' ], }, { firstName: 'Cinema3', lastName: 'Manager', email: 'sample@sample.com', _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5', roles: ['hospital', 'hr' ], }, { firstName: 'Cinema4', lastName: 'Manager', email: 'sample@sample.com', _id: '5e3cf62cc631a8788be59fc5', roles: [ 'ward', 'hospital', 'hr' ], }]},
      result = input.users.reduce((r, o) => {
                  o.roles.forEach(role => {
                    r[role] ??= [];
                    r[role].push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o)));
                  });
                  return r;
              },{});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can I have alternate of `??=` in my code its throwing error

Comment: Yes you can use `r[role] = r[role] || [];`

Answer (score 0):

You can just go over each input element and then over each role in the input element and add the element to the corresponding array in a by-role object (creating the array as needed):

```js
const byRole = {}
for (const obj of input.users) {
  for (const role of obj.roles) {
    if (!byRole[role]) byRole[role] = []
    byRole[role].push(obj)
  }
}

console.log(byRole)
```

There would be also a less imperative, more functional approach, if you prefer that:

```js
const byRole = Object.fromEntries(
  [...new Set(input.users.map(obj => obj.roles).flat())]
    .map(role => [role, inputArray.filter(obj => obj.roles.includes(role))])
)

console.log(byRole)
```

Since you seem to be working with MongoDB records, another possibility would be to group it already in your database query, offloading that work to the database server:

```js
const queryResult = await db.users.aggregate([
  // Optionally add a $match step here to filter: { $match: { ... } }
  { $addFields: { role: '$roles' } },
  { $unwind: '$role' },
  { $group: { _id: '$role', records: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } }
])
const byRole = Object.fromEntries(
  queryResult.map(({ _id, records }) => [_id, records])
)
```

(This will leave an extra field `role` in each record though, but I guess you won't mind.)

Comment: I am unable to get expected outbut by this, Can you help ;(

Comment: Please show your attempt, I cannot help if you don't know what you tried and why it failed.

Comment: Note that all my suggestions use the input _array_ directly, which would be the value of the `users` property of the object you showed, not the entire object.